# pythonchallenge.com 4 in ruby solution

Tags: ruby

Is there a 'better/alternative/more readable' solution to http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php than the ruby code below?
I can understand it but it just doesn't seem very clear to me...

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w
# encoding: utf-8

require 'net/http'

Net::HTTP.start 'www.pythonchallenge.com' do |http|
  nothing = 12345

  nothing = case http.get("/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing=#{nothing}").body
    when /(\d+)$/ then $1.to_i
    when /by two/ then nothing / 2
    when /\.html/ then puts $`
  end while nothing
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was ok but let's try to make it a little more readable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w
# encoding: utf-8

require 'net/http'

Net::HTTP.start 'www.pythonchallenge.com' do |http|
  next_one = 12345

  while next_one
    response = http.get("/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing=#{next_one}").body

    case response 
      when /Divide by two and keep going./ then
        next_one = next_one / 2
      when /and the next nothing is (\d+)/ then
        next_one = $1.to_i
      else
        puts "Solution url: www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing=#{next_one}"
        next_one = false
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: I get the following error with your code  "in `block in <main>': undefined method `/' for "92118":String (NoMethodError)
 from /Users/batman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:627:in `start'
 from /Users/batman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:490:in `start'
 from 7.rb:3:in `<main>'"

Comment: @raphael_turtle : Ok, on `next_one = $1.to_i` the `to_i` was added. (I was trying it from a higher value).